# How to allocate and deallocate an array of function pointers and keep valgrind happy?

Tags: c++, memory-management, function-pointers

How can I allocate and deallocate an array of function pointers in C++? I've tried two different strategies, first using single pointers and the second using double pointers but I can't seem to make valgrind happy. Here is my situation:

```
// function pointer
typedef double(*function_ptr)(double);

// function that adhers to the interface set by function_ptr
double do_nothing(double x) {
    return x;
}

// dynamically create array of @param size function pointers, all pointing to do_nothing
function_ptr **make_function_ptr(int size) {
    function_ptr xp = &do_nothing_transform;
    function_ptr* xpp = &xp;
    auto **trsfm = (ESfcnTrsfm **) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr *));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        trsfm[i] = (ESfcnTrsfm*) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr));
        trsfm[i] = xpp; // same as trsfm[i] = ...
    }
    return trsfm;
}

// free the array of function pointers
void free_function_ptr(function_ptr  **fun, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        free(fun[i]);
        fun[i] = nullptr;
    }
    free(fun);
    fun = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: You have two assignments to `trsfm[i]` in succession. The second erases the address returned by `malloc`. That may be what valgrind is complaining about, but we do not know because you have not shown us the valgrind messages. You also did not provide code we can compile or run through valgrind ourselves: This code uses `do_nothing_transform` and `ESfcnTrsfm` but has no declarations of them. Further, your uses of `auto` and `nullptr` look like C++, but you tagged the question C. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @AdrianMole The question text specifically mentions C, and the original tag was C, so I reverted the edit. The only indication of C++ I can see may be `auto` but that has a different meaning in C. I don't think the usage is correct, but the intention is for this to be C.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Possibly - I'll not get into an "edit war" with you. But the use of `nullptr` and the explicit cast of `malloc` also hints at C++.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm using a C++ compiler (and followed compiler hints for the auto and nullptr) but its C code that I'm editing.

Comment: @AdrianMole You're right that the code contains more elements of C++ than I noticed, but the presence of *"in C"* in the question clearly sets the intention.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Most C++ compilers have a flag to indicate that it should compile the source code as C instead. Considering checking if yours does and using it if possible. C and C++ are different languages and it is important to understand that they are not interchangeable, and neither is a subset of the other. Legal C code is often not legal C++ code and vice-versa.

Comment: Is there any benefit from doing so? Apart from not getting C++ suggestions from CLang tidy. The C code is wrapped in an extern "C" block.

Comment: The `extern "C"` block only affects the calling conventions for external functions (no name-mangling). The code is still compiled as C++. The `auto` and `nullptr` keywords won't work if you compile your code as C.

Comment: The advantage is that you will compile the code as it is intended. If you try to write C code, and then compile it with C++, the compiler can't tell you when you've written invalid C code which would be valid in C++. You are effectively writing C with C++ features (a nice way of saying very bad C++) and labeling it as C. People who try to use it as C won't be able to and people who try to use it as C++ will have a very bad time, because it was not intended to be C++.

Comment: In fact, the very presence of `extern "C"` ***requires*** the code to be compiled as C++. That ain't valid in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `make_function_ptr` function allocates space for **only one** `function_ptr` in the 'outer' table, rather than allocating space for `size` pointers. So, this:

```c
    auto **trsfm = (ESfcnTrsfm **) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr *));
```

Should be:

```c
    auto **trsfm = (ESfcnTrsfm **) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr *) * size); // Need to multiply by "size"
```

Without this, the `trsfm[i]` access in the subsequent `for` loop is undefined behaviour, when `i` is anything other than zero.

Furthermore (as pointed out in the comments), you are allocating memory in that `for` loop unnecessarily. You need only assign the address of the `dummy` routine to the allocated table entries:

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    //  trsfm[i] = (ESfcnTrsfm*) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr)); // Unnecessary!
        trsfm[i] = xpp; // same as trsfm[i] = ...
    }
```

(And, similarly, you don't need the `for` loop to free those pointers in your `free_function_ptr` function.)

Answer (score 0):

This line is obviously wrong:

```
auto **trsfm = (ESfcnTrsfm **) malloc(sizeof(function_ptr *));
```

You need to allocate that multiplied by "size".